# How can I integrate existing C# application with Spring.NET

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an existing application in C# and I want to integrate with Spring.NET application which are using AOP(Aspect Oriented Programming).Then how I should integrate it together to develop a new application.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For some examples, read the AOP Quickstart in the Spring.NET reference docs here: http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html